# Thumbnail stopped appearing in my Tableau Public Profile

Tags: tableau-api, thumbnails

I have 3 vizzes in my Tableau Public Profile and they were all showing their thumbnails up to this morning when a friend told me one of them was black. This vizz that is no longer showing a thumbnail is a story (the other 2 are dashboards) and the black color is the background of my story.

I tried finding an answer online but it seems to me that this is an issue with Tableau Public. There was a thumbnail before, but it simply disappeared. There are multiple posts on the web but no single solution.
[image: vizz not showing thumbnail]
Does anyone one knows any trick to deal with this?

This is my Tableau Public Profile: https://public.tableau.com/profile/filipeanalytics

Thank you!